# Error: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, custom-controller

I am getting an Error:Attempt to de-reference a null object

> Error is in expression '`{!PopulateLatituteLongitude}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page mapsdemo: Class.SearchController.PopulateLatituteLongitude: line 42, column 1`

I don't see anything wrong and I am hoping some one can point out my issue.

Just trying to get a list of strings. Thanks!

My class:

```
public class SearchController {

private String searchZip;
private List<String> geocode;

public string getSearchZip()
{
    return this.searchZip;
}

public void setSearchZip(String s) 
{
    this.searchZip = s;   
}

public List<String> getGeocode()
{
    return this.geoCode;
}

public PageReference PopulateLatituteLongitude()
{     
    string apiKey = 'MyAPIKeyHereRemovedForSharing'; //This is the key for server applications. Put this in a custom setting 
    String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?';
    url += 'components=postal_code:' + this.searchZip; 
    url += '&key=' + apiKey; 
    Http h = new Http(); 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    req.setHeader('Content-length', '0'); //I am not sure if this is required or not 
    req.setEndpoint(url); 
    req.setMethod('POST'); 
    String responseBody = ''; 
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
    responseBody = res.getBody(); /*Response body will include this… 46.8647086 -96.8262901 */ 
    string geometryString = ''; 
    string locationString = ''; 
    geometryString = SearchController.getValueFromXMLString(responseBody, 'geometry'); 
    locationString = SearchController.getValueFromXMLString(geometryString, 'location'); 

    string latitudeValue = SearchController.getValueFromXMLString(locationString, 'lat'); 
    string longitudeValue = SearchController.getValueFromXMLString(locationString, 'lng'); 
    this.geocode.add(latitudeValue);
    this.geocode.add(longitudeValue);

    return null;
} 

private static String getValueFromXMLString(String xmlString, String keyField) 
{ 
    String valueFound = ''; 
    if(xmlString.contains('<' + keyField + '>') && xmlString.contains(''))
    { 
        try
        { 
            valueFound = xmlString.substring(xmlString.indexOf('<' + keyField + '>') + keyField.length() + 2, xmlString.indexOf(''));
        }
        catch (exception e)
        { 
            system.debug('Error in getValueFromXMLString. Details: ' + e.getMessage() + ' keyfield: ' + keyfield);
        } 
    } 
    return valueFound; 
}
```

}

My VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="SearchController" >
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <h1>Testing Search Controller</h1>
        <p>ZipCode: <apex:inputText value="{!searchZip}"/></p>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!PopulateLatituteLongitude}" value="Test"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Which line is 42?

Comment: @AdrianLarson this.geocode.add(latitudeValue);

Comment: You never initialize the property before trying to add to it

Comment: @Eric Wow I feel dumb thanks! Works now, Post it up and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the geocode if it is null when you get it

```
Public List<String> getGeocode()
{

    If(this.geoCode == null) this.geoCode = new String[]{};
    return this.geoCode;
}
```

Or simply instantiate it in the constructor, or .......